# pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: error

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I started 3 `mongod` process each on different `port` with different `dbpath`.

```
./bin/mongod --replSet foo/tauquir:27018,tauquir:27019 --rest
./bin/mongod --port 27018 --dbpath /data/db1 --replSet foo/tauquir:27017 --rest
./bin/mongod --port 27019 --dbpath /data/db2 --replSet foo/tauquir:27017 --rest
```

Started the connection as:

```
CONN = Connection("tauquir:27017", slave_okay=True)
CONN.admin.command("replSetInitiate")
CONN = Connection(["tauquir:27018", "tauquir:27019"])
```

Traceback I am getting:

```
     CONN.admin.command("replSetInitiate")
              File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pymongo-1.9-py2.6-linux-
        i686.egg/pymongo/database.py", line 293, in command msg, allowable_errors)
              File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pymongo-1.9-py2.6-linux- 
    i686.egg/pymongo/helpers.py", line 119, in _check_command_response raise 
OperationFailure(msg % response["errmsg"])
            pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('replSetInitiate', 1)]) failed: 

all members and seeds must be reachable to initiate set
```

Answer (score 1):

replSetInitiate is a one time command so you probably don't want that coded with your connection init, but after that line you need to instantiate your python client with connection information for all 3 mongod servers.

In your example you are replacing your `CONN` variable with a connection only to 27018 and 27019

```
db = Connection(["tauquir:27017", "tauquir:27018", "tauquir:27019"])
```